# Spring Security Ajax Login

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am currently working on Spring Security 4. Everything works fine if using default login method. However, in practice, I need to login using Ajax method.

spring-security.xml

```
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <form-login
        login-processing-url="/resources/login-processing" 
        default-target-url="http://127.0.0.1:57633/" 
    />
    <csrf request-matcher-ref="csrfSecurityRequestMatcher"/>
    <!-- <csrf disabled="true" /> -->
</http>
```

In the `controllers`, I use `@PreAuthorize` annotation. In jQuery, the ajax request is as follows:

```
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost:8080/myapp/resources/login-processing",
        data:{username:$("#inputLogin")[0].value,
              password:$("#inputPassword")[0].value
             },
        method:"POST",
        success: function(data, textStatus, request) {
            console.log(request.getResponseHeader())
        }
    })
    .done(function(data, textStatus, request) {
        console.log(request.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie"))
    })
    .error(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

Even though I set `permitAll`, it still response 403 error with the following response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:1116
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 18 Apr 2016 02:07:26 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=974B1629ECE3EB289F35097C9E9D9FDC; Path=/cancercloud/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

What should I do to configure Ajax login?

Comment: username or password maybe wrong? try hardcoded. Did you try to change "http://localhost:8080/myapp/resources/login-processing" to only the servlet name?

Comment: please include csrf also in ajax

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends 
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler{
        private RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();

        public RequestCache getRequestCache() {
            return requestCache;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
             SavedRequest savedRequest
             = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);

             response.setHeader("targetUrl", determineTargetUrl(authentication));
           if (savedRequest == null) {
               clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
               return;
           }
           String targetUrlParam = getTargetUrlParameter();
           if (isAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl()
             || (targetUrlParam != null
             && StringUtils.hasText(request.getParameter(targetUrlParam)))) {
               requestCache.removeRequest(request, response);
               clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
               return;
           }

           clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
        }

        public String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication) {
            boolean isUser = false;
            boolean isAdmin = false;
            boolean isRegisteredUser = false;

            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
            System.out.println("Authorities......" + authorities);
            // List<Role> roles = roleRepository.findRoleByPrivleges(authorities);
            List<String> privleges = new ArrayList<>();
            for (GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {

                // System.out.println("Authority = " + authority.getAuthority());
                privleges.add(authority.getAuthority());
                if (authority.getAuthority().equals("READ_USER")) {
                    isUser = true;
                    isAdmin = false;
                    isRegisteredUser = false;
                    break;
                } else if (authority.getAuthority().equals("CREATE_USER")) {

                    isAdmin = true;
                    isUser = false;
                    isRegisteredUser = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isUser) {
                return "/spring-mvc/jk";
            } else if (isAdmin) {
                return "/spring-mvc/admin/adminHome.htm";
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
        }

    }
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageResource;

    @Autowired
    private LocaleResolver localeResolver;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // setDefaultFailureUrl("/main?error=true");
        // response.setStatus(HttpStatus.);
        // super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);

        Locale locale = localeResolver.resolveLocale(request);

        System.out.println("********************************************");
        System.out.println(exception.getMessage() + " " + locale.getLanguage() + "_" + locale.getCountry());
        System.out.println("********************************************");

        String errorMessage = null;
        if (exception.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("blocked")) {
            errorMessage = messageResource.getMessage("auth.message.blocked", null, locale);
        } else if (exception.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("User is disabled")) {
            errorMessage = messageResource.getMessage("auth.message.disabled", null, locale);
        } else if (exception.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("User account has expired")) {
            errorMessage = messageResource.getMessage("auth.message.expired", null, locale);
        } else {
            errorMessage = messageResource.getMessage("message.badCredentials", null, locale);
        }

        System.out.println(errorMessage);
        HttpSession session = null;
        session = request.getSession();

        /*
         * HttpSession session = request.getSession(); try{ Exception e=
         * (Exception)
         * session.getAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
         * System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         * session.removeAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
         * }catch(NullPointerException npe){ npe.printStackTrace(); }
         */
        // session.setAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage);
        session.setAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION, errorMessage);
        System.out.println(session.getAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION));
        System.out.println("********************************************");
        //response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.setHeader("errorMessage", errorMessage);
        return;
        //response.getWriter().flush();

        // authenticationFailureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure(request,
        // response, exception);
        // request.setAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage);

    }

}


    $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#login').validate({

                submitHandler : function(form, event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('#signInBtn').attr('disabled', true);
                    alert('submit handler for login');
                    var formdata = $('#login').serialize();
                    alert(formdata);
                //  $("#validation_sign_in_error").empty();
                    $.ajax({
                        type : 'POST',
                        url : '/spring-mvc/j_spring_security_check',
                        data : formdata,
                        beforeSend:function(xhr){
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Ajax-Call","true");
                        },
                        success : function(response, status, jqXHR) {
                //           alert(status);alert(response);
            //      alert(jqXHR.status);
                //   alert( jqXHR.getResponseHeader("targetUrl"));
                   var targetUrl=jqXHR.getResponseHeader("targetUrl");
                   if(jqXHR.status==200 && targetUrl != null)
                         window.location=targetUrl;

                   if(jqXHR.getResponseHeader("errorMessage") != null){
                         //      var springException = '${sessionScope.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION}';
                          //     alert('Exception = ' +springException);
                             $("#validation_sign_in_error").empty();
                             $('#validation_sign_in_error').text(jqXHR.getResponseHeader("errorMessage"));
                             $("#validation_sign_in_error").show();
                             $('#signInBtn').attr('disabled', false);
                   }

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```